# Using Qt Framework create an API call in c++ class

Tags: c++, qt, api, authentication

I am new to the Qt Framework and I have to implement an API call to Login the users. I created an ApiManager class where I want to create only the calls that the app will use, so that they are accessible from C++ classes and also the QML.

I created a local function that simulates a login, but I want to implement the real API call now. I just don't know how to implement it and what kind of libraries I have to import or include.

**Header file apimanager.h**

```
#ifndef APIMANAGER_H
#define APIMANAGER_H

#include <QObject>

class ApiManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(UserLevel)
public:

    enum UserLevel {
        UL_Unknown = 0,
        UL_Master = 1,
        UL_Administrator = 2,
        UL_Operator = 3
    };

    explicit ApiManager(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void loginComplete(bool logged, UserLevel userLevel);

public slots:
    void login(QString serverAddress, QString username, QString 
password);
};

#endif // APIMANAGER_H
```

**Class apimanager.cpp**

```
#include "apimanager.h"
#include <QDebug>

ApiManager::ApiManager(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void ApiManager::login(QString serverAddress, QString username, 
QString password)
{
    qDebug() << "loggin into" << serverAddress << "with user" << 
    username;

    bool logged = false;
    UserLevel ul = UserLevel::UL_Unknown;
    if (username=="master" && password=="123") {
        logged = true;
        ul = UserLevel::UL_Master;
    } else if (username=="admin" && password=="123") {
        logged = true;
        ul = UserLevel::UL_Administrator;
    } else if (username=="operator" && password=="123") {
        logged = true;
        ul = UserLevel::UL_Operator;
    }

    emit loginComplete(logged, ul);

}
```

If anyone can tell me how to write an API call with a similar structure of my "fake" login function I'll be thankful.

Thanks to all

Comment: It is very hard to help when we don't know how the API looks like. Please provide more code!

Comment: Sorry for that, the API isn't ready yet, but you can show me a simple login with username and password if you want, I only want to know how to create the base function, a generic API call

Comment: Well, an API call can be anything. It can be a plain function call (if you get a library) or a network message

Comment: So, I have to comunicate with a server, the function will have the username, the password and the server address (ip:port), here i call the function. The server will respond with an authentication (like string "logged") and the userlevel, that is spicified in the database as the username and the password. Hope all these informations help you understand and maybe help me too :-)

Comment: If you need any other information to understand just ask

Comment: In case you are accessing a REST-API, have a look at [QtRestClient](https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtRestClient). If it's another kind of HTTP based API, take a look at [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html). For any other kind of API you will most likely have to implement whatever protocol is used yourself, via a [QTcpSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll immediately take a look

Answer (score 0):

@Marco,

Here is the skeletal Http request response example.
It is using Network classes from Qt to send the request and receive the response for the same.

https://github.com/ramkumarrammohan/Qt_HttpNetworkRequest

If you have any doubts about this please let me know, Thanks